# Automation data-change firing issue using Selenium, jQuery and RFT

Tags: javascript, rft, ibm-rational, pega, webui

Hey all I am using RFT in order to automate a page on a Pega website page. However, the automation doesn't seem to be able to fire off the change event of the input that I am inserting a string of text into. This input box seems to be located **inside** an **iframe** and perhaps this is the reason why its not firing the onchange event when losing focus on that input box?

RFT does use **Selenium** in their program to interact with the web page.

The html of the input box:

```
<input 
    data-id="204083727717650" 
    data-ctl="["TextInput"]" 
    id="BBOX" 
    maxlength="15" 
    validationtype="required" 
    value="" 
    name="$PpyWorkPage$pBBOX$pBBOX" 
    class="leftJustifyStyle" 
    data-change="[["refresh", 
                   ["otherSection",
                    "RecordInformation", 
                    "", 
                    "&amp;=", 
                    "", 
                    "BBOXOnChange,",
                    ":event",
                    "",
                    "pyWorkPage.BBOX"
                   ]
                 ]]" 
    type="text">
```

The Selenium code I have tried is this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("PegaGadget")));     

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("BBOX")));
final WebElement BBOXInputBox = driver.findElement(By.id("BBOX"));

BBOXInputBox.click();
BBOXInputBox.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
BBOXInputBox.sendKeys("204083727717650");
Thread.sleep(2000);
BBOXInputBox.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
Thread.sleep(2000);
BBOXInputBox.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
Thread.sleep(2000);
BBOXInputBox.sendKeys("1");
Thread.sleep(200);
BBOXInputBox.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
Thread.sleep(2000);

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName_U")), 5, 5).click().build().perform();

driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName_U")).sendKeys("something");
```

And I am trying my best to find this function above in their 30 or so of .js files for any one page.

So someone more knowledgeable than I in the area of this type of coding in JS please set up and let me know what I should be looking for in the .js source code so that I can fire this **change event** manually within code.

It seems when I click on the text box, input a few letters and then either tab or click on another input box on that same form it fires some type of event/function that populates a label on the page.

What I have been looking for within the .js source code would be a function called **refresh(...)** or something along the lines of **refresh: function(...)...** or **_refresh: function(...)...** but I haven't been able to find anything that resembles the parameters its sending to that function.

Comment: anyone have any input on this?